# Collecting the result of PySpark Dataframe filter into a variable

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am using the `PySpark` dataframe. My dataset contains three attributes, `id`, `name` and `address`. I am trying to delete the corresponding row based on the `name` value. What I've been trying is to get unique `id` of the row I want to delete

```
ID = df.filter(df["name"] == "Bruce").select(df["id"]).collect()
```

The output I am getting is the following: `[Row(id='382')]`

I am wondering how can I use `id` to delete a row. Also, how can i replace certain value in a dataframe with another? For example, replacing all `values == "Bruce"` with `"John"`

Comment: You just need to extract the ID value from the output. `id_vals = [r['id'] for r in ID]`

Comment: You cannot use an indices in your DataFrame. Spark DataFrames have different structure behavior than pandas. Also Spark isn't a RDBMS. So unless you filter and collect, not much to do. Spark DataFrame are not intended to be used as lookup tables.

Comment: Ofc you can transform that collected entry into one entry using head() and map.

Comment: Thanks @pault. That's what I was wondering for.

Comment: @zimmer np, I added an answer with an explanation. I can't help but thinking this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it that you're trying to do? There's likely a better solution than using collect to gather one `id` at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs for [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.collect()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.collect), the function:

> Returns all the records as a list of Row.

The fields in a [`pyspark.sql.Row`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row) can be accessed like dictionary values.

So for your example:

```python
ID = df.filter(df["name"] == "Bruce").select(df["id"]).collect()
#[Row(id='382')]
```

You can access the `id` field by doing:

```python
id_vals = [r['id'] for r in ID]
#['382']
```

But looking up one value at a time is generally a bad use for spark DataFrames. You should think about your end goal, and see if there's a better way to do it.

---

**EDIT**

Base on your comments, it seems you want to replace the values in the name column with another value. One way to do this is by using [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when).

This function takes a boolean column expression as the first argument. I am using `f.col("name") == "Bruce"`. The second argument is what should be returned if the boolean expression is `True`. For this example, I am using `f.lit(replacement_value)`.

For example:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
replacement_value = "Wayne"
df = df.withColumn(
    "name",
    f.when(f.col("name") == "Bruce", f.lit(replacement_value)).otherwise(f.col("name"))
)
```

Comment: Thanks @pault. I was trying to delete the rows with name "Bruce". I know my method was too complicated but I came up with an easier. Here: 

`df = df[df["name"] != "Bruce"]`

Can I replace a particular name with another string too?

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: condition should be a Column` when I write the code above. I have tried with `==` too. Is there something I could be doing wrong?

Comment: @zimmer I've added an edit to the answer with some more explicit syntax using `pyspark.sql.functions.col`.