# pyspark dataframe to rdd taking just values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, flatmap

I'd like to convert dataframe to rdd but just take values like this rdd format:

[(1, 19997, 16091), (1, 24374, 7017), (3, 20124, 21453)]

tried this `final_df_new.rdd.map(lambda x:(x))` but it gives

```
[Row(total_properties_products_quantity=1, userIds=19997, productId=16091),
 Row(total_properties_products_quantity=1, userIds=24374, productId=7017),
 Row(total_properties_products_quantity=3, userIds=20124, productId=21453)]
```

and i tried this:

```
final_df_new.rdd.map(tuple).take(5)
```

gives:

```
[(1, 19997, 16091),
 (1, 24374, 7017),
 (3, 20124, 21453)]
```

Does anyone know how to do?

Comment: `[d.asDict().values() for d in data]` where `data` is your list of `Row`s but this assumes the `asDict` is ordered (which depends on your python version).

Comment: what's the difference between your expected output : [(1, 19997, 16091), (1, 24374, 7017), (3, 20124, 21453)] and the one that you got from final_df_new.rdd.map(tuple).take(5) ? They look the same to me. can you explain a little? Also please provide the code to create your test dataframe

Comment: See also: [Collecting the result of PySpark Dataframe filter into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428928/collecting-the-result-of-pyspark-dataframe-filter-into-a-variable)